# Finding mode in List of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, mode

How can I find the mode of a list of numbers? I know the logic of it (I think) but I don't know how to implement that logic or convert what my brain thinks into workable code.

This is what I know:

I need to have a loop that goes through the list one time to see how many times a number is repeated and an array to save the times a number is repeated. I also need to tell my program to discard the lesser amount once a larger one is found.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  If so, are there limitations regarding what library methods you can use?

Answer (score 4):

A linq approach, more concise but almost certainly less efficient than Yeldar Kurmangaliyev's:

```
int FindMode(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    return data
        .GroupBy(n => n)
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count)
        .First()
        .Key;
}
```

This does not handle the case where `data` is empty, nor where there are two or more data points with the same frequency in the data set.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right:

**Let we have** a *list* of *numbers*:

```
List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7 } );
```

You need to have *a loop that goes through the list one time*:

```
foreach (var val in myValues)
{
}
```

*to see how many times a number is repeated in array to save the times a number is repeated*:

```
Dictionary<int, int> repetitions = new Dictionary<int, int>(); 
foreach (var val in myValues)
{
    if (repetitions.ContainsKey(val))
        repetitions[val]++; // Met it one more time
    else
        repetitions.Add(val, 1); // Met it once, because it is not in dict. 
}
```

Now, your dictionary `repetitions` stores how many (exactly **value**) times **key** value repeated.
Then, you need to find the record of mode (i.e. record with the highest time of repetitions (i.e. highest value)) and take this one. LINQ will help us - let's sort the array by value and take the last one...or sort it descending and take the first one. Actually, that's the same in terms of result and productivity.

```
var modeRecord = repetitions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First();
// or
var modeRecord = repetitions.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Last();
```

Here it is! Here we have a mode:

```
List<int> myValues = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7 } );
Dictionary<int, int> repetitions = new Dictionary<int, int>(); 

foreach (var val in myValues)
{
    if (repetitions.ContainsKey(val))
        repetitions[val]++; // Met it one more time
    else
        repetitions.Add(val, 1); // Met it once, because it is not in dict. 
}

var modeRecord = repetitions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).First();

Console.WriteLine("Mode is {0}. It meets {1} times in an list", modeRecord.Key, modeRecord.Value);
```

Your mode calculation logic is good. All you need is following your own instructions in a code :)

Comment: Good answer.  More verbose, but more efficient (fewer key lookups): `int count; if (repetitions.TryGetValue(val, out count)) repetitions[val] = count + 1; else repetitions[val] = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative LINQ approach:

```
var values = new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7 };

var mode =
    values
        .Aggregate(
            new { best = 0, best_length = 0, current = 0, current_length = 0 },
            (a, n) =>
            {
                var current_length = 1 + (a.current == n ? a.current_length : 0);
                var is_longer = current_length > a.best_length;
                return new
                {
                    best = is_longer ? n : a.best,
                    best_length = is_longer ? current_length : a.best_length,
                    current = n,
                    current_length,
                };
            }).best;
```